# Session caching problem

Tags: php

I have a strange problem with php sessions. I use them for authorization on my site. I store two variables - currently logged in user's id and username in session. When I log in with one username, than log out and log in again with another username the previous user's id is returned using the session variable instead of the current user.

The most strange thing is that this happens only when it comes to insert some data into database. When I directly echo this variable the correct id is displayed, but when I insert new record into database this variable sends incorrect id.

Here is the php code I use for sending data into database:

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect database
require_once 'dbc.php';

$authorID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if ( $authorID != 0 ) {
        $content = htmlentities($_POST["answ_content"],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
        $dro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $qID = $_POST["question_ID"];
        $author = 'avtori';


        $sql="INSERT INTO comments (comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date, comment_content, user_id) 
            VALUES
          (NULL, '$qID', '$author', '$dro', '$content', '$authorID')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

} else {
    echo 'error';
}

?>
```

Can anyone please help?

Here is the logout function:

```
function logout()
{
global $db;
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
mysql_query("update `users` 
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
            where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
}           

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Here is the authentication script:

```
include 'dbc.php';

$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value); //get variables are filtered.
}

if ($_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
{

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value); // post variables are filtered
}


$user_email = $data['usr_email'];
$pass = $data['pwd'];


if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
    $user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
} else {
      $user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";

}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE 
           $user_cond
            AND `banned` = '0'
            ") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

  // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num > 0 ) { 

    list($id,$pwd,$full_name,$approved,$user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if(!$approved) {
    //$msg = urlencode("Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code");
    $err[] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code";

    //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
     //exit();
     }

        //check against salt
    if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) { 
     // this sets session and logs user in  
       session_start();
       session_regenerate_id (true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

       // this sets variables in the session 
        $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
        $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        //update the timestamp and key for cookie
        $stamp = time();
        $ckey = GenKey();
        mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

        //set a cookie 

       if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                  setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                   }
        if(empty($err)){            
          header("Location: myaccount.php");
         }
        }
        else
        {
        //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
        $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
        //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
        }
    } else {
        $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
      }     
}
```

Comment: Please, show us how do you perform the logout.

Comment: `htmlentities` is not suitable to protect agains SQL injections (if it’s that what you’re using it for). Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, prepared statements oder a parameterized query builder for that.

Comment: Oh, and how do you authenticate your users?

Comment: I added logout and login script to the question...

Comment: If you try echoing out the query in the authentication script, does it look right, and does it pull the correct data if you run it directly in the database?  Also, make sure both the user_name and user_email fields are unique in the database or you will get multiple rows returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *kills* me how many people post code vulnerable to **[SQL injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)**!

```
<?php
$content = htmlentities($_POST["answ_content"],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
        // ^ Attack  vector
$dro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$qID = $_POST["question_ID"];
    // ^ Attack vector
$author = 'avtori';

$sql="INSERT INTO comments (comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date, comment_content, user_id) 
      VALUES
      (NULL, '$qID', '$author', '$dro', '$content', '$authorID')";
?>
```

**[Sanitize your database inputs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)**!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) to make sure to use a new session ID and destroy the old one:

```
session_start();
if ($userIsAuthentic) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

If you’re not using PHP 5.1.0 or higher you can use this equivalent to substitute the missing *delete_old_session* parameters:

```
session_start();
if ($userIsAuthentic) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

Comment: What is the $userIsAuthentic variable?

Comment: `$userIsAuthentic` is intended to be a variable that holds the state whether the current user is authentic or not.

Comment: First thing to check is whether the browser is caching the page when it shouldn't - use a wiresniffer or read your webserver logs (cehck any proxies too). Next check you haven't got session fixation problems.

Comment: But why should it display the correct information on one page and incorrect on the other...

Answer (score 0):

Try nuking the session from orbit: [session_destroy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Call it, nuke their session cookie, end the script immediately, and direct the user to the login page.  They'll get a new session there and log in properly.